# Ubuntu freezes and can't recover

Tags: crash

I had this problem since i switched to linux (ubuntu). I am using Ubuntu for more than half a year, and I allways had this problem. It doesnt appear very often, but it will appear at least every once a week. It happens randomly, when I open a program, Ubuntu crashes and can't recover at all (Not even with Ctrl + Alt + F2). Before it crashes, the monitor blinks for less than a second, and everything freezes. I can't even controll the mouse. The system doesn't respond at all, and only thing I can do is turn it off on button.

**Edit:**

ls -alt /var/crash
`total 20900
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 јул  4 04:23 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.uploaded
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 јул  4 04:23 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 mile     whoopsie        0 јул  4 04:23 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.upload
-rw-r-----  1 mile     whoopsie 18834361 јул  4 04:23 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root     whoopsie        0 јул  4 04:21 .lock
-rw-r-----  1 mile     whoopsie  2551993 јул  1 18:36 _usr_lib_unity-settings-daemon_unity-settings-daemon.1000.crash
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 апр 22 02:38 ..`

free -h
`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3,9G        1,9G        1,0G        151M        971M        1,5G
Swap:          4,0G        325M        3,7G`

swapon -s
`Filename               Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5               partition   4191228 333104  -1`

cat /etc/fstab
`UUID=9695a0cd-6a66-4156-a506-3f2444669560 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`
`# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation`
`UUID=a7057283-8830-4f79-ad49-f8bfcb937ba3 none            swap    sw              0       0`

Comment: I presume your question is: How can I gather sufficient information for developers to investigate the issue and possibly even help me out of my misery?

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `ls -alt /var/crash` and `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Please copy/paste this output into your question, not the comments, please. Do you have a Intel Bay Trail processor? Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I edited the article. My processor is Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q6600  @ 2.40GHz

Comment: Is "јул  4" July 4, or June 4? Is your Chrome up to date? Reboot the computer, DON'T even start Chrome, and use Firefox for a while, and lets see if the problem occurs again.

Comment: @heynnema sorry, it's in cyrillic, it is july 4. So you think the Chrome is causing problems? I noticed it buggs all the time, but I can't tell if Chrome crashes the system. I will try with Firefox

Comment: Chrome crashed most recently, and it is known as a memory hog. You only have 4G RAM. Using Firefox instead of Chrome might eliminate one possibility of your problem. You might edit your question title... as your machine is freezing, not crashing. Report back when you have more info with Firefox.

Comment: @heynnema yesterday it froze two times, but each time it recovered after 10 seconds (which is not like before when i had to restart the whole system).  I have to test it for about a week, if the system doesn't freeze again, i will write it here.

Comment: When you say freeze now, do you mean that the Firefox window goes dim grey, and then comes back after 10 seconds? Use the `free -h` command regularly and watch how much swap space gets used. We may have to increase swap space. Keep me posted.

Comment: ps: How many other applications do you run at the same time as Chrome/Firefox? How many tabs do normally have open? Do you know how to use the `top` command?

Comment: @heynnema I meant whole system froze, and recovered. I know how to use top command, but i don't have that many applications opened. Same goes with tabs, about 3-4 opened. 
But now even Firefox freezes regulary, but it recovers. Also i noticed that Nautilus file explorer froze couple of times

Comment: The `free -h` command run semi-frequently will tell us if memory/swap is fully/over utilized. The `top` command, running all the time in a terminal window, will tell us if some application/process is all of a sudden consuming 100%+ of the CPU time. Temporarily turn off **all** startup applications, and log out/in. What video driver/version are you running?

Comment: @heynnema As i was logging in now in my system, it froze again, and i recovered it by CTRL + ALT + F2, then returning to GUI. My video driver from nvidia, version a1 I think.  I want to ask how much Swap memory is optimal to be used, because my system uses very little, usually it uses 10MB, right now it uses 0 - is it a good or bad to use little swap memory?

Comment: The size of swap depends on the size of RAM, how many apps are running at the same time, and generally how the system is used. Apps with large data sets usually require lots of RAM, and plenty of swap. With 4G RAM, I usually recommend 8G swap. Do the steps outlined in my last comment, and hopefully we'll get a clue. Is your Nvidia driver from the Nvidia web site, or the Ubuntu repos?

Comment: ps: it sounds like your Nvidia driver came from the Nvidia web site, rather than from the Ubuntu repos. You might try uninstalling it and using the repos version. I've heard that fixes some problems. Continue with the `free -h` and `top`, and turning off startup apps.

Comment: @heynnema how can I check where are my drivers from? I never actually installed anything, and I never went on Nvidia site. I rememeber that i chose option when i installed the system that it can install third party drivers or something like that. I am now running `top` command all the time, and I noticed that my swap memory is allways 0% used.

Comment: Do `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` and `dpkg -l *microcode* | grep ii`. Swap will start to get used as you open multiple apps, and/or have multiple tabs open in your browser. Open `Software & Updates`, Additional Drivers tab, and tell what you see there. Do you know how to view `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @heynnema no, I'm not familiar with viewing it

Comment: @MilePanic you haven't shown me the output of the dpkg commands, and the drivers tab.

Comment: @heynnema 
dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii  
`ii  nvidia-304                       304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.135
ii  nvidia-current                   304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-current
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-304            304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-settings                  361.42-0ubuntu1          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver`

Comment: dpkg -l *microcode* | grep ii  
`ii  intel-microcode 3.20151106.1 amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs`

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I'm out of ideas. Sorry. Please let me know if you find a fix.

Comment: @heynnema thank you man for helping me. I know it's hard to find a solution because it happens so randomly

Comment: @heynnema I think I figured out what the problem might be. I've been watching `htop` command, and it seems that very often 1 CPU core gets on 100%, and the system kinda slows down a little until core usage gets lower. It didn't freeze yet, but i think that is the reason

Comment: Try and identify which process is at the top when CPU spikes.

Comment: @heynnema well it mostly happens when i browse the web. I dont have many tabs open, and I use firefox.

Comment: @MilePanic try running Firefox without extensions and see if the problem goes away.